# Create a draggable handlerbar in jQuery , which updates value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create a draggable incremental indicator(i don't know whats the exact terminology for this.), basically something like below:

[image: Click to enlarge]

Now i came across **[THIS](http://skidding.github.io/dragdealer/)** plugin. Now this plugin works fine, but i was just wondering if there are other plugins like this one that i can use and get a similar effect ?

P.S. I don't want to use jQuery UI , just jQuery and jQuery plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this one: http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/

It's possible to use this library with or without jQuery

Repo: https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider

Answer (score 1):

These are called sliders.
You can use this one if you want
https://refreshless.com/nouislider/slider-values/